# StanfordCoreNLP Spanish module

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the Spanish module in the `StanfordCoreNLP` library, but I keep getting a message `AttributeError: type object 'StanfordCoreNLP' has no attribute 'Pipeline'`. Any ideas how can I access the Spanish module?

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

# stanfordnlp.download('es')
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP.Pipeline(lang="es", treebank="es_ancora")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process Spanish in Python, we have two options.

1.) Run a Stanza neural pipeline (this will allow for `tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma, depparse,ner`).  See here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/installation_usage.html

2.) Access the CoreNLP server with Stanza's client (this will also include constituency parse via the `parse` annotator) See here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html

If you have any other questions please let me know.